# How can I separate an Excel document into different files?

Tags: excel, csv, export

I have an excel document that have this structure:

[Customer name] [Customer street] [Customer post code]

It has a couple of thousands rows, and I need to separate the into their own files.

I have tried to find someone else that has made the same thing or similar, but without success.

I want to create a script that asks me "Which post code interval do you wanna export?" and answer to that might be "100-300". Then the script exports those rows into a new txt/csv-file that is tab or comma delimited.

Is this even possible in Excel? I am developer but not an Excel developer :D haha.

Would be so grateful to receive some examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter option in you excel file it has several option for example you can set a filter on Post code must be bigger then 100 and less then 300
->
[image: Filter option]

Comment: That is true. But can it automatically export it for me?

Comment: You will need to develop a macro Excel.